# Mudei o endereço da página de http para https e agora está dando erro

Tags: wordpress, http, https

Eu mudei de http para https o endereço deste site aqui http: http://akauasilva.adv.br/ , fiz isso na área de configurações do wordpress.. 
E agora o site é encaminhado para página de erro da hostagor. O que faço? Eu não entendo nada sobre http e https.

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro indica que o cabeçalho de sua página já foi enviado.

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /home/akaua982/public_html/wp-config.php:1) in
>   /home/akaua982/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1211

quando utilizamos uma linguagem server side qualquer espaço em branco antes da abertura do php é considerado uma saída de cabeçalho para o cliente. Como no caso já houve o envio do cabeçalho no arquivo /home/akaua982/public_html/wp-config.php na linha 1 como indicado na mensagem de erro é impossível alterar o cabeçalho na linha 1211 do arquivo /home/akaua982/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php porque ele já deu saída. Procure no seu arquivo wp-config.php linhas em branco antes da abertura do código php ou após o fechamento e remova. Isto deve corrigir o problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]